# Preparing dataset for analysis with T-SNE

Tags: python, mds

A little of the background story.. I am trying to get a qualitative/quantitative judgement on whether there exists a useful solution(if any) that a convolutional neural network can arrive at for a set of synthetic images containing 3 classes.

Now, I am trying to run TSNE on a folder containing 3195 RGB images of resolution 256x256.

First question I would like to ask is, am I converting my image folder into an appropriate format for usage with TSNE? The python code can be seen here  https://i.stack.imgur.com/79gNy.png.

Secondly, I managed to get the t-sne to run, although I am not sure if I am using it correctly, which can be seen here. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtOlR.png . The sourcecode is basically just a slight modification from Alexander Fabisch's MNIST example on Jupyter Notebook(apologies, however I cannot post more than two links since reputation <10.) 
So, I would like to ask whether is there anything blatantly wrong for forcing a TSNE architecture used for MNIST dataset on a set of RGB images?

Lastly, I encountered a difficulty for the code in the second imgur link posted above with the below code,

```
imagebox = offsetbox.AnnotationBbox(
            offsetbox.OffsetImage(X[i].reshape(256, 256)), X_embedded[i])
```

The first argument for offsetbox.AnnotationBbox is a 256x256 image(because my image resolution is such), which basically covers up my entire screen, obscuring the results), but I get an error when i try to change it:

```
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

So, how can I reduce the size of the images being plotted?(or other ways to work around the issue)

Comment: Work backwards - what results do you expect from this? The specifics will also depend on which language you want- you have tagged this C++ *and* python. Choose.

Comment: Furthermore, this shows an example using images as input (for python) http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/manifold/plot_lle_digits.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-manifold-plot-lle-digits-py

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Hi guys, thank you all for the feedbacks. I apologize for the sloppy post and also, have already corrected my post, removing the C++ tag as well, to narrow this down to just python. Also, please let me know if I need to further improvise the question.

Answer (score 0):

Well.. solved everything using the C++ codes provided for bh-tsne. Kindly close this thread, apologies for any inconvenience caused.